# Firebase Query and rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This seems like a pretty simple problem, I think I just have been staring at it for too long. I'm trying to query transaction-history on my database, but I only want users to be able to read transaction documents that they are involved with. I know that query contraints have to match the rules constraints, and mine seem to. Can someone find whats going wrong here?

Firebase Rules

```
    match /transaction-history/{transactionId}{
        allow read: if isPurchaserOrReciever(getTransaction(transactionId));
    }
    function isPurchaserOrReciever(transaction) {
        return transaction.purchaserId == request.auth.uid || transaction.recieverId == request.auth.uid;
    }
    function getTransaction(transactionId) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/transaction-history/$(transactionId)).data;
    }
```

Database Query within my app.

```
await firestore
        .collection('transaction-history')
        .where('purchaserId', isEqualTo: myId)
        .getDocuments()).documents;
```

Comment: What's currently wrong? Is everybody being blocked or is no one being blocked?

Comment: everyone is being blocked

Comment: but If i run the simulator, everything works like I expect it to

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why my previous query wasn't working. While doing more research I found a way to simplify the query, and that isn't throwing any errors. I'm still interested if someone can tell me what was wrong with my previous rules or query.

```
    match /purchase-logs/{purchaseId}{
        allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }

    match /transaction-history/{transactionId}{
        allow read: if resource.data.purchaserId == request.auth.uid || resource.data.recieverId == request.auth.uid;
    }
```